# Hive rows generation from a column value

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How can I generate the rows in Hive based on a single column value. For Eg,

I have the below table data. I need to generate the similar rows (all fields same) but with all column values for rating?

```
item_id   cost   rating
23        1290   0.08
14        1498   0.06
```

I need the output as shown below.

```
item_id   cost   rating
23        1290   0.08
23        1290   0.07
23        1290   0.06
23        1290   0.05
23        1290   0.04
23        1290   0.03
23        1290   0.02
23        1290   0.01
14        1498   0.06
14        1498   0.05
14        1498   0.04
14        1498   0.03
14        1498   0.02
14        1498   0.01
```

Answer (score 3):

For example like this:

```
with initial_data as(
select stack(2,
23, 1290, 0.08,
14, 1498, 0.06
) as (item_id, cost, rating)
) 

select item_id, cost, (i+1)/100 as rating
from
(
select d.*, cast(d.rating*100 as int)-1 as n --the number of rows to generate
  from initial_data d
)s lateral view posexplode(split(space(s.n),' ')) e as i, x  --generate rows with numbers (i)
order by item_id desc, rating desc; --remove ordering for faster processing if you do not need ordered output
```

Result:

```
OK
23      1290    0.08
23      1290    0.07
23      1290    0.06
23      1290    0.05
23      1290    0.04
23      1290    0.03
23      1290    0.02
23      1290    0.01
14      1498    0.06
14      1498    0.05
14      1498    0.04
14      1498    0.03
14      1498    0.02
14      1498    0.01
Time taken: 74.993 seconds, Fetched: 14 row(s)
```